# Numpad symbols not getting typed on clicking them

Tags: android

I have created a form based app. There is a form in which I have created EditText for typing  numeric data programmatically. I have successfully opened the numpad.But when I click any symbols present in numpad like .,+ etc., they dont get typed in EditText. Here is my sample code ,

```
 edtValue=new EditText(SuperUserAddStudentActivity.this);
                                edtValue.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SuperUserAddStudentActivity.this, R.drawable.edt_parameter_background));
                            edtValue.setSelected(false);
                            edtValue.setPadding(EditTextPaddingLeft,EdittextPaddingTop,EditTextPaddingRight,EditTextPaddingBottom);


                            // TODO: 16/8/18 change here
                            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams edtValueLayoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, iParameterEditTextHeight);

                            edtValueLayoutParams.setMargins(0,ParameterMarginTop,0,0);
//                            edtValueLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                            edtValue.setLayoutParams(edtValueLayoutParams);
                            edtValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            edtValue.setHint(p.getName());
                            edtValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                                    p.setEnteredValueByUser(s.toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        //add it to same layout

                        llTempHolder.addView(tvParameterLabel);
                        if(edtValue!=null)
                        {
                            llTempHolder.addView(edtValue);
                        }
```

Please help me in this regard. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the code from
                            edtValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
 to                             edtValue.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is your TextChangedListener. you have 3 functions which are called when text is changed, but none of the functions changed the text-value of edtValue.

in onTextChanged try something like: 
edtValue.setText(s.toString());

I am not sure myself, but I do not have enough reputation to comment unfortunately

Comment: My problem is not that. I have symbols like dot,plus,etc on my numpad. But when i click them they don't get typed. Only numbers get typed. I want to type something like 99.9. But it will type 999.